# How to create a kind of SDK for JainSIP?

Tags: jain-sip

I'm gonna use jainSIP in a softphone and I wonder somethings.
For events like hang up the call, hold, resume, cancel, reject the call, How the call Id can be pulled up to the softphone ? I know during an answer, it's the request.getHeader which provide call Id but for these events ?

Thank you  in advance !

Answer (score 1):

JAIN SIP gives you raw access to the message, you will have to build the functions of the SDK yourself ie call, hold, resume, cancel, reject.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought. On the other hand, do you know how callbacks work with JAIN SIP ? For example, for a call rejected ? I have to build this mecanism too ?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to built that as well. On receiving the 486 response, you will need to notify the listener of your call rejected mechanism. Are you trying to build an SDK for PCs or for Mobile devices (Android, iOS) ?

Comment: I am trying to build an SDK for PCs. Did you already do that ?

Comment: No only for Browsers with WebRTC and Android and iOS. You can check https://jitsi.org/ and ask on their mailing lists. They may have abstracted the code in such a way that you could reuse parts of it to create an SDK

Comment: my pleasure, please upvote one of the answer so future readers will know which answers was worthwhile to you ;)